Can I take a value of a variable initialised inside a loop and use it outside a loop in java?
I am trying to build a Rock Paper Scissor game. In which I am trying to take the value of a variable initialised inside a while loop in this case integer variable w and l. But taking an error that variable is not initialised.

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HEHE_19_Rock_Paper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = 0;
        int w,l;

        while (t <= 3) {
// Player Logic of Picking
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 'S' for Scissors, 'R' for Rock and 'P' for Paper");
            String i = s.next();
            int input;
            i = i.toLowerCase();
            switch (i) {
                case "s" -> input = 1;
                case "r" -> input = 2;
                case "p" -> input = 3;
                default ->
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + i + "Only 3 inputs are available 'S','R' and 'P'."); // suggested by Intelli J
            }
            if (input == 1) {
                System.out.println("You Have Picked Scissors!!!");
            } else if (input == 2) {
                System.out.println("You Have Picked Rock!!!");
            } else if (input == 3) {
                System.out.println("You Have Picked Paper!!!");

            } else {
                System.out.println("What are you doing!!! Only 3 inputs are available 'S','R' and 'P'.");
            }
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
// Computer Logic of Picking

            Random rand = new Random();
            int response = rand.nextInt(1, 4);

            if (response == 1) {
                System.out.println("PC Has Picked Scissors!!!");
            } else if (response == 2) {
                System.out.println("PC Has Picked Rock!!!");
            } else if (response == 3) {
                System.out.println("PC Has Picked Paper!!!");
            }

            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            w = 0;
            l = 0;
// Deciding Logic
            if (input == response) {
                System.out.println("===========The Game is Draw!!!===========");
            } else if (input == 1 && response == 2) {
                System.out.println("==========PC has won the Game!!==========");
                l++;
            } else if (input == 2 && response == 3) {
                System.out.println("==========PC has won the Game!!==========");
                l++;
            } else if (input == 3 && response == 1) {
                System.out.println("==========PC has won the Game!!==========");
                l++;
            } else if (response == 1 && input == 2) {
                System.out.println("==========You have won the Game!!==========");
                w++;
            } else if (response == 2 && input == 3) {
                System.out.println("==========You have won the Game!!==========");
                w++;
            } else if (response == 3 && input == 1) {
                System.out.println("==========You have won the Game!!==========");
                w++;
            }
            t++;
        
        }
        switch(w > l){
            case true -> System.out.println("You have won the game!!");
            case false -> System.out.println("You have lost the game!!");
            default -> System.out.println("The game is Draw");
        }
    }
}


I have tried to introduce variable outside the loop as I only want the values inside the variable but i didn't works.

In Java, variables that are declared inside a loop (or any block) are only accessible within that block. If you want to use the values of w and l outside the while loop, you need to declare them outside the loop and initialize them before using them.
Here is the example
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t = 0;
        int w = 0; // Initialize w outside the loop
        int l = 0; // Initialize l outside the loop

        while (t < 3) { // Changed t <= 3 to t < 3 to play 3 rounds

Update according to the comment
Instead of directly comparing w and l using a w > l, you can use the Integer.compare(w, l) and change code to this
switch (Integer.compare(w, l)) {
    case 1 -> System.out.println("You have won the game!!");
    case -1 -> System.out.println("You have lost the game!!");
    default -> System.out.println("The game is Draw");
}


The loop has little to do with the error. The problem is the compiler thinks there's a code path that doesn't assign a value to w or i, which occurs if the while condition is false. The compiler doesn't consider the logic that t is assigned a value that makes the condition true; it just sees a possible false. Initialization of w and i is the solution for this error, no matter what the rest of the code looks like.

@Bohemian I understand the issue. The error occurs because the compiler doesn't consider the logic that t is assigned a value that makes the while condition true; it just sees a possible false path where w and i are not initialized. Initializing w and i outside the loop resolves this error, regardless of the rest of the code. Thank you for pointing that out!

So, if I understood right I may be use the values that are increamented after getting a specifics conditions right I will be able to use the values inside w and l outside the loop and use it inside the switch to declare winner loser or draw if i had insialised the values outside the loop. So, if w will be 1 and l will be 2 inside the loop, will the switch will able to decide based on values inside the loop?? Just for clarification

@GoDnCRAFT Yes, you understood it correctly. If you initialize w and l outside the loop and then update their values inside the loop based on the game results, you will be able to use their final values outside the loop. So, if w is 1 and l is 2 inside the loop, the switch statement outside the loop will be able to decide based on these final values.
